# Второстепенное и основное значение букв

Tags: русская-графика

Светлана (оовооооо) давно (овооо) мечтала (овооооо) остаться (вововввв) дома (ооов) одна (вооо).
о - основное, в - второстепенное. Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно ли я делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Светлана (оовоооов)-редуцированный Ъ-второстеп. знач.?

мечтала(овоооов)на конце редуцированный

остаться(вооовввв)[а-ослабл.с т а ц ъ]

Comment: то есть в каждом слове ошибки!Значит я тему не поняла!

Comment: Людмила, а по какой это системе или методике? 
Я только после вашего ответа понял, о чем вообще речь. 
Но это разговоры уровня *аллофон vs фонема*, при чем тут буквы?
Кто и кого так учит-то?

Comment: Это в вузах и колледжах.Речь о многозначности букв русской графики. Так, в слове дом буква о в главном значении, а в слове дома - во второстепенном значении - редуцированная, то ли о, то ли а, то ли ы. Только вот не все признают такой подход, кто-то говорит, что второстепенным является только значение, обусловленное орфографическим правилом, где можно сделать ошибку. Вот я и спрашиваю, какой подход у них в вузе - редуцированный в конце слова ведь не допускает другого написания, он считается второстепенным значением или нет? По Гвоздеву -да.

Comment: Ужас...  :((( Я чувствую себя чужим на этом "празднике жизни".  
    
А какое значение "главное"? Алфавитное? Более частное?  
Я не уверен, что даже у гласных (А, О, Е) оно так...    
А у **Ь** какое главное значение? У **Й**?    
    
Гвоздева знаю только по фамилии, но не важно.

Comment:  Я, Ю, Е, Ё - два значения-смягчение согласных и j+ои...,оба основные, Ь-смягчение согласных-одно основное, й-полугласный звук(и-краткое)

Comment: Ах, так "основных" еще может быть больше одного?!  
Спасибо.  

Хотя...   
А вот с Й всё равно непонятно. Они что не различают Й в "йод", "майор" и в "бой", "лейка"?! А ведь оно может передавать ещё и ноль звука: майя, паранойя.    
Не, я пасс...  )))